# Using JMock on the Android

Tags: android, classloader, jmock

How can I use JMock on the Android?  I've several posts saying its not possible, but surely there's **some** way to do it?

The issue seems to be getting the Android to even recognize the JMock jar file.  So maybe there's a solution with putting the jar into assets and making a custom class loader?  That seems like a lot of trouble, but does it sound like it would work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have JMock working inside Android opensource test projects.

Yes: JMock code executes on the device in your hand ;-)

I've used:

- jmock-2.5.1.jar
- **Repackaged** hamcrest-all-1.1.jar (I'll explain)
- jmock-junit3-2.5.1.jar

See the following for a Android JMock Test case http://github.com/olibye/ToneDial/blob/master/ToneDialTest/src/net/xpdeveloper/dialer/test/TestDialServiceTest.java

Here are the three issues I had to overcome:

---

### Hamcrest Packaging

The multiple packaging of Hamcrest fails Android package validation.

The error you get in Android ADK is:-
Error generating final archive: duplicate entry: LICENSE.txt

**Solution**

unzip hamcrest-core-1.1.jar
unzip hamcrest-library-1.1.jar in the same directory.

This the second unzip overwrites MANIFEST.MF and LICENCE.TXT.

zip ../hamcrest-all-1.1.jar

Initially I raised this with Steve and Nat for JMock

- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JMOCK-242

However it's really Joe's packaging issue in Hamcrest (so I just posted it there ;-)

- http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=125

---

### JUnit Packaging

The JUnit plugin in eclipse contains a subset of Hamcrest.

**Solution**
You need to move the JUnit library down your classpath after JMock, in the eclipse project properties.

---

### Android Packaging

JUnit v3 is part of android.jar so you can't use JUnit 4 style JMock tests.
No annotations for us yet ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Times have changed and @byeo's answer is more complex than necessary due to things being fixed and improved.

With Android Studio 3.1.4, I was able to get JMock and Hamcrest working easily, at least in Unit Tests.  I added the following dependencies to my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies{
    ....
    testImplementation files('../../../../lib/jmock-2.8.3/jmock-2.8.3.jar')
    testImplementation files('../../../../lib/jmock-2.8.3/jmock-junit4-2.8.3.jar')
    testImplementation files('../../../../lib/jmock-2.8.3/jmock-legacy-2.8.3.jar')
    testImplementation files('../../../../lib/jmock-2.8.3/objenesis-2.1.jar')
    testImplementation files('../../../../lib/jmock-2.8.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')
    testImplementation files('../../../../lib/jmock-2.8.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar')
    testImplementation files('../../../../lib/cglib-nodep-3.2.5.jar')
    ....
}
```

However, I'm unsure if JMock will work correctly in tests that use the Emulator or real hardware because of this question:

[JMock jars do not work inside Android test project (project doesn't build )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363064/jmock-jars-do-not-work-inside-android-test-project-project-doesnt-build)